# how to get selected text in editor from outside the editor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I need to have selected text in editor from outside the editor. I am using this `editor.getSelection().getSelectedText()` but it returns nothing. How can I get that text??

Answer (score 0):

maybe try

```
editor.getSelection().getSelectedText().getNative();
```

Comment: No its not working. alert(editor.getSelection().getSelectedText()); returns empty string but alert(editor.getSelection().getSelectedText().getNative()); does not even show anything.

Comment: You may find that the alert removes focus from the box (and therefore the selection). When the focus is restored the selection would be also. Specifically I have seen this issue with IE.

Answer (score 0):

The following is available since 3.6.1 and works smoothly in 4.1:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstanceName.getSelection().getSelectedText();
```

In case of any troubles, please provide additional info: browser (**vendor + version**), **CKEditor version** and **config**.

Comment: I have tried this code in ff chrome and also in IE with CKEditor versin 3.6.5 but its not  working .